# Menu item without a modifier key

Tags: c++, menu, gtk, menuitem, menubar

I want to create menu using GTK+. My question is: is there any way to create menu items with accelerators, but without a modifier key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put an underscore before the underlined letter, it will be underlined and used as a shortcut. For example, in pygtk:

```
copy = gtk.ImageMenuItem(gtk.STOCK_COPY)
copy.set_label("_Copy It!")
```

Comment: You can also access them with the keyboard, for example Alt+F S will save file in many programs. Or you could try catching the key press event: http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq05.005.htp